# Joomla Random image module with recursive search for images

Tags: image, random, module, joomla, joomla1.6

I'd love to have a random image module which uses recursion while searching for images so that the random image would be from the directory I've chosen or its subdirectiories. I have found Random Image Plus but it's for Joomla 1.5 not 1.6 which I'm using. Could you tell me if there are other modules for Joomla 1.6 or if the Random Image Plus module could be easily upgraded to be 1.6 compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many image plugins, recursive perhaps not but i guess you will find quite many. Perhaps its good to know that 16native is the search query in the extension diretory for joomla 1.6 plugins. Try

http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=random+image+16native

(66 hits)

Comment: The first result was what I exactly searched for. Speaking about "recursion" I wanted to have a module which would read also subfolders of the specified folder and I found such a module thanks to you :).

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just update the one you are using fairly easily. Most of the changes tend to be in the XML manifest.

http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6